# Making a "Race" Between Two Variables

Tags: r

I would like to make two variables ("a" and "b") that keep:

- taking a random value less ALWAYS than their current value (i.e. a1 > a2 > a3 ...> an , b1 > b2 > b3 ... bn ALWAYS)
- until one of them less than or equal to 0:

I showed a demo below:

```
#iteration 1
a1 = 100 - rnorm(1,5,10)
b1 = 100 -rnorm(1,5,10)

a2 = a1 - rnorm(1,5,10)
b2 = b1 -rnorm(1,5,10)

a3 = a2 - rnorm(1,5,10)
b3 = b2 -rnorm(1,5,10)

#etc.
```

I would then like to repeat this many times. In the end, this would look something :

[image]

Currently, I am doing this manually, and then using the `bind_rows()` command to "pile" each iteration on top of each other. Can someone please show me a faster way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a small`recursive` function:

```
fun <- function(x){
  if(any(x < 0)) x 
  else rbind(x, fun(x - abs(rnorm(length(x),5,10)) ))
}
```

Now for 1 draw of A and B:

```
set.seed(1)
fun(c(A=100, B=100))
          A          B
x 100.00000 100.000000
x  98.73546  93.163567
x  95.37918  72.210759
x  87.08410  69.006075
x  77.20981  56.622828
x  66.45199  54.676712
x  46.33418  45.778279
x  45.12178  28.631280
x  28.87247  24.080617
x  24.03437   9.642254
   10.82216  -1.296759
```

We can use this within a function to replicate. Will maintain BASE R although can be simplified in tidyverse:

```
random_seq <- function(n, start){
  fun <- function(x){
    if(any(x < 0)) c(x)
    else rbind(x, fun(x - abs(rnorm(length(x),5,10)) ))
  }
  R <-replicate(n, data.frame(fun(start), row.names = NULL), simplify = FALSE)
  S <- do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, id = seq(R), R))
  U <-transform(S, time = ave(id, id, FUN = seq_along))
  reshape(U, dir='wide', idvar = 'id', sep='')
}

set.seed(1)
random_seq(4, c(A=20,B=20))
   id A1 B1         A2        B2        A3        B3        A4       B4
1   1 20 20 18.7354619 13.163567 15.379176 -7.789241        NA       NA
4   2 20 20 11.7049223 16.795316  1.830632  4.412069 -8.927182 2.465953
8   3 20 20 -0.1178117 11.101568        NA        NA        NA       NA
10  4 20 20 18.7875942  2.853001  2.538285 -1.697663        NA       NA
```

BONUS:
if interested, `fun` can directly reproduce the names:

```
fun <- function(x){
   nms <- as.numeric(sub('\\D+', '',names(x))) + 1
   names(x) <- paste0(sub("\\d+", '', names(x)), nms)
  if(any(x < 0)) c(x)
  else c(x, Recall(x - abs(rnorm(length(x),5,10)) ))
}
fun(c(A0=20, B0=30))
       A1        B1        A2        B2        A3        B3 
20.000000 30.000000 11.234808 23.323201 -9.611483  1.544311
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that runs a single start to 0, nicely configurable, and we can use `replicate` to run it as many times as needed, returning a `list`.

```
to_0 = function(start = 100, fun = runif, ..., n = 1000) {
  if(start <= 0) stop("Must start greater than 0")
  result = start - c(0, cumsum(fun(n, ...)))
  if(all(result > 0)) stop("Didn't reach 0, set a higher n or check inputs.")
  first_0 = match(TRUE, result < 0)
  result[seq_len(first_0)]
}
```

I used `runif` as the default instead of your `rnorm` because you say you want the series to be strictly decreasing, but `rnorm` is sometimes positive and sometimes negative so it will sometimes lead to increases.

I cut off the series at the first negative value. Since the lengths of each run are different, a `data.frame` seems like a bad choice, keeping them in a `list` is better. We can use `lengths()` to see how long each vector in the list is.

The function is parametrized, so you can easily try out other distributions or custom functions, e.g., `to_0(start = 100, fun = rexp, rate = 0.1)`. Below I demonstrate with the uniform distribution starting at `10`.

```
set.seed(47)
race = replicate(n = 100, to_0(start = 10))
head(race)
# [[1]]
#  [1] 10.00000000  9.02303800  8.64912196  7.88761993  7.06512831  6.49158390  5.80017147  5.41110962  4.94216364  4.39885390  3.47396185
# [12]  3.33516427  2.63317707  2.47098343  1.87167641  1.36564030  0.46366678  0.06316398  0.03221901 -0.03913915
# 
# [[2]]
#  [1] 10.00000000  9.27320918  8.54814801  7.77974923  7.34440424  7.27499236  6.76825217  6.75134855  6.20214287  5.43031741  4.56633348
# [12]  3.59288910  3.24547860  2.60269295  1.75639299  1.73279651  1.72371866  1.38211688  0.71933800  0.04916749 -0.40714758
# 
# [[3]]
#  [1] 10.00000000  9.08923490  9.06189460  8.69397353  8.30179409  8.11077841  7.96295850  7.49701585  6.52812608  6.26480567  5.34558158
# [12]  5.31801508  4.90573089  3.98774633  3.89046321  3.70358854  3.61482042  3.53824450  3.36900151  2.86522484  2.23295349  1.80544403
# [23]  0.82311022  0.73664857 -0.09385818
# 
# [[4]]
#  [1] 10.0000000  9.2172681  8.4175584  8.1672679  7.3683421  7.3373712  7.0319788  6.6512214  5.7210315  5.2732412  4.6817849  4.1065416
# [13]  3.9452541  3.4009742  2.5018050  1.5316136  0.7175295  0.4410275 -0.1859260
# 
# [[5]]
#  [1] 10.00000000  9.91914621  9.90238843  9.82993154  9.33156028  8.90827720  8.44160294  7.46348397  6.76539075  6.27298443  5.97401412
# [12]  5.03395592  4.55537992  3.75737919  2.82175869  2.75045000  2.70081885  2.67523320  2.20266408  2.12695183  1.25880525  0.57011279
# [23]  0.03173135 -0.79275633
# 
# [[6]]
#  [1] 10.0000000  9.9292630  9.6154147  9.0754730  8.7814754  8.5273701  7.6998567  6.8127609  5.9944598  5.6232599  5.1505038  4.8676191
# [13]  4.6337121  4.5868438  4.0435219  3.0981151  2.2621741  1.9925101  1.2104707  0.9334569  0.7574446  0.1643009 -0.5220925

lengths(race)
 #  [1] 20 21 25 19 24 23 21 24 23 22 25 24 19 19 23 17 19 23 25 21 24 25 18 22 24 25 19 19 23 22 19 26 20 23 24 24 22 21 25 23 21 28 19 20 16 20
 # [47] 22 25 20 22 23 23 24 22 19 23 23 23 22 18 22 23 24 21 21 23 21 22 20 25 22 23 21 17 20 20 16 25 21 21 21 20 20 19 24 19 23 24 26 25 20 21
 # [93] 23 17 27 18 30 24 21 23
```